# What does the following SPF record allow?

Tags: email, email-spam, spf

**v=spf1 ip4:211.121.22.56 a mx a:server.hostname.com ~all**

My understanding is it allows the following to send out emails:

ip4: 211.121.22.56

a: A record (where website is hosted)

mx: whatever the MX record says

a: this server name

And nothing other than the above 4 places

Am I correct?

Comment: I think this post is better suited for the "Server Fault" site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the "a"s but yes, it validates to whoever checks it - that mail is allowed to be sent in this domain from either the IP address or the server.hostname.com.

Q. Should be on serverFault.